# How to move edge-based SKPhysicsBody?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a node with edge-based physics body. Another node with volume-based body is pinned to the first one by SKPhysicsJointFixed. And there's a need to move edge over the scene, but, as I found out, It's not a simple task. All the "physics movements" are results of forces and impulses, which affect only on volume-based bodies, not edge-based ones. And when I move my edge-based body by simply changing its position (x,y), the SKPhysicsJoints between edge and volume just break. Is there proper way to move edge-based physics body?

Comment: no "proper" way because static bodies are supposed to be static (aka immovable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to do that with static edge-based bodies. But there's a trick with setting `pinned` property of volume-based physics body, which actually fixes node to parent with a pin joint. Additionally set `rotationEnabled` to `NO` and voila!

Answer (score 1):

Basically no, as the [documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html):

> An edge is a static volume-less body. Edges are **never moved** by the simulation and their mass doesn’t matter.